# How to drag Angular dynamic created modals

Tags: angular

Hey i am using angular 5 in my application. I am using angular material modals which is dynamically created, i need that complete modal to be draggable. I tried ngDraggable but it is not working also it's not dragging the complete modal only content is draggable. 
Is there any other work around or solution ?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-draggable-dialog ?

Comment: I am using Angular 5 and this example has Angular 6. Will this work ?

Comment: You can try it. Basically this is a simple directive. Just copy the directive, it will works.

Comment: After few changes it was working. Thanks. There is one more question how I can disable the overlay created by this angular modal and copy Data from page where it opens and paste into modal.

Comment: To disable overlay, set `hasBackdrop` to `false` when opening the dialog.
To inject data: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples (see `Injecting data when opening a dialog`).

Comment: I've added the answer. You can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-draggable-dialog

Copy the directive `JpDraggableDialogDirective` from this stackblitz to your project.